# When variable value have space between word, doesnt show any result WP_Query

Tags: wp-query

I  now create a widget, that return the post has same tag enter in inputbox
I use WP_Query, but i have a problem. when i enter word with space in inputbox dont return any result, but when enter word dont have space its work correctly

This is my inputbox

```
<input type="text" class="widefat" id="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_id('tagCategory')) ?>"
               name="<?php echo esc_attr($this->get_field_name('tagCategory')) ?>"
               value="<?php if (isset($tagCategory)) echo esc_attr($tagCategory); ?>"/></p>
```

This is my Query

```
$wpbp = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'tag'       => $tagCategory,
        'posts_per_page' => $numberOfPosts,
        'orderby'   => 'id',
        'order'     => 'ASC'
     )
 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct behavior. And the reason for this problem is pretty simple...

When you use `tag` param in `WP_Query`, then it searches for tags with given slug (string used in URLs) - so there should be no spaces. There are 7 parameters for slug searching in WP_Query:

- tag (string) - use tag slug.
- tag_id (int) - use tag id.
- tag__and (array) - use tag ids.
- tag__in (array) - use tag ids.
- tag__not_in (array) - use tag ids.
- tag_slug__and (array) - use tag slugs.
- tag_slug__in (array) - use tag slugs.

As you can see none of above takes name as value.

If you want to search for tag name, then you should use `tax_query`:

```
...
'tax_query' => array(
    array( 'taxonomy' => 'post_tag', 'field' => 'name', 'terms' => $value )
)
```